# What are the laws for trespass in Austria?

Tags: criminal-law, trespass, civil-legal-system, austria, continental-law

Bobbi, a national or equivalent of Austria, after admitted to enter, refuses to leave from public (government) premises of Austria at the close of business hours despite having been given due notice.

What laws and rulings are applicable for willful trespass or similar actions Austria?

Comment: Why would this be a duplicate?  Austria is not Germany.

Comment: I don't understand why you made the most recent edit. Do you want us to close this as a duplicate?

Comment: I appreciate the OP's intent was to create a single thread for all EU trespass laws, and requested the merger (found in the edit history) but that plan seems to have fallen by the wayside, hence my VTR as not a duplicate

Comment: Since our practice is that questions that specify a jurisdiction may also be answered for any other jurisdiction, any answer to this question would also be on topic for the question about Germany, and vice versa. Thus there are effectively duplicates.